# Meteor JS failing to complete installation on macbook pro

Tags: meteor, failed-installation

I have been trying to install Meteor JS on my macbook pro but I keep getting the following:

**Meteor 2.5.1 has been installed in your home directory (~/.meteor).
Writing a launcher script to /usr/local/bin/meteor for your convenience.
This may prompt for your password.
Password:**

After the semi-colon, there is a key symbol which does not blink, and so it is not allowing me to type in my laptop password.

Could anyone help, please?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have Meteor installed before? Your Mac is Intel or M1 ? What command did you use?

Comment: Hi, Ricardo. thanks for your question. My Mac is M1. I used the following to install it:  curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh